# Casting generic types in Java

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have the following custom iterator:

```
class PetIterator<T extends Pet> implements Iterator<T>
```

I have this class:

```
class Dog extends Pet
```

But the Java compiler won't allow this cast (`iterate` returns a `PetIterator`):

```
Iterator<Dog> dogs = (Iterator<Dog>)petstore.iterate (“dogs”);
```

How can I retrieve my Golden Retrievers, other than writing:

```
PetIterator dogs = petstore.iterate (“dogs”);
...
Dog dog = (Dog)dogs.next();
```

Comment: Can you please give the return type of petstore.iterate(String)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could rewrite your `iterate(String)` method to this:

```
class PetStore {
  <T extends Pet> PetIterator<T> iterate(Class<T> clazz);
}
```

Then you could use that method type-safely

```
PetIterator<Dog> dogs = petstore.iterate (Dog.class);
// ...
Dog dog = dogs.next();
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `PetIterator<T extends Pet>` is not a `PetIterator<Dog>`. It can be any `Pet`, and then your `iterator.next()` will fail to cast to `Dog`.

Why don't you simply use `class PetIterator implements Iterator<T>` (which is the same `T` is the one in the petstore object, which I guess is also generic)